# PHPJasperXML has a deprecated constructor on PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7

I'm using class PHPJasperXML.inc.php version 0.9b to generate my PDF report, it was no problem when running on PHP 5.*
got an error message when running on PHP 7

"Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; PHPJasperXML has a deprecated constructor in /class/PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 4"

this file use a function name with the same name as the class was used as the constructor

I've tried to Replace public function PHPJasperXML() with public function __construct(), that's not solving yet.

I can't find that file which supports for PHP 7

How would I fix it?
Thanks so much.

Comment: What happens when you use __construct()? Their github hasn't been touched in years. I'd start migrating to another library sooner than later.

Comment: that's not working, just showed a blank form

Comment: What's in the php error log?